# Python JSON to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

With this line of code in python I created JSON containing multiple messages:

```
notification = [{
                 'message': 'This is the homepage',
                 'username': 'User',
                 'room': 'Home',
                 'timestamp': '11:59' 
                },
                {
                 'message': 'Hello World!',
                 'username': 'User',
                 'room': 'Home',
                 'timestamp': '12:00'
               }]

return render_template("chat.html",  messages = notification)
```

Now I would like to print all the messages on the webpage, so I sent all the information to javascript. But when the output of the following script returns an empty string.

```
const message = `{{messages}}`;
console.log(message);
```

Why is the string empty?

Comment: It seems like you are passing a list and then using it as a string in JS. Try changing that and post the ouput

Comment: Is this Flask?  Is the js code embedded in the html file?

Comment: Yeah it is. `render_template` is a flask function. I don't know about the rest of the file. Also the script is probably embedded into the HTML. I just assumed it was, my bad.

Comment: Yes it is indeed a flask function and the script is embedded in the HTML

Comment: Can you try without the quotes around `{{messages}}`?

Comment: That gives an error 'messages is undefined'

Answer (score 2):

What you are passing in the `notification` variable isn't actually JSON, it's a Python list. You need to use `json.dumps` to convert it to an actual JSON string.

Then in your JS you will need to wrap the string in quotes (single quotes best as JSON uses double quotes) so that your JS is syntactically valid. You can then even use Javascript's `JSON.parse` to convert it to a JS array:

```
const message = '{{messages}}' ;
console.log(JSON.parse(message) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the notification as json to the template

Flask

```
return render_template("chat.html",  messages = json.dumps(notification))
```

Template

```
const message = JSON.parse('{{messages | tojson | safe}}');
console.log(message)
```